# C program will not divide two scanf inputs correctly

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf, division

I am attempting to create a program that takes the input of a users gallons used and miles driven for three tanks for an assignment. The issue I have been having is that the for loop is either not correctly dividing the two values addressed in the input to a third value (average miles per gallon) or the program is not addressing the inputs correctly. But I am still new to this, so I am not sure where the problem is located.

```
    for(i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
    {
        /* Define calculations */
        /* ------------------- */

        ave_miles = miles / gallons;
        total_miles = total_miles + miles;
        total_gallons = total_gallons + gallons;
        total_ave_miles = total_miles / total_gallons;

        /* Propmpt user for miles and gallons used and calculate miles per gallon. */
        /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

        printf("Enter the number of gallons used for Tank #%i: ", i);
        scanf("%f", &gallons);
        while ( (c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);

        printf("Enter the number of miles driven: ");
        scanf("%f", &miles);
        while ( (c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);

        printf("*** The miles per gallons for this tank is %.1f\n\n", ave_miles);
    } /* end for loop */

    /* Display and calculate the total miles per gallon for the three tanks. */

    printf("Your overall average of miles per gallon for three tanks is %.1f\n\n", total_ave_miles);
    printf("Thank You for using the program. Goodbye.\n");

} /* end main */
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: regarding; `/* Define calculations */
        /* ------------------- */

        ave_miles = miles / gallons;
        total_miles = total_miles + miles;
        total_gallons = total_gallons + gallons;
        total_ave_miles = total_miles / total_gallons;`   These executable statements are in error.   They should be comments, not executable code.

Comment: these two statements: `while ( (c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);` are not needed as the input format specifier `%f` will consume leading 'white space'

Comment: Aside: you don't need the newline-removal code here. Most format specifiers for `scanf` automatically filter leading whitespace, so all you need is the two `scanf` statements. Exceptions are `%c` and `%[]` and `%n`.

Comment: in general, cannot perform math on variables until after the variables are initialized/assigned some value

Comment: 3629249 and Weather Vane, my first issue I had with the code was that the second scanf would be completely ignored and printed out on one line with the following printf. Originally, it looked like this. ` printf("Enter the number of gallons used for Tank #%i: ", i);
  scanf("%f", &gallons);
  
  printf("Enter the number of miles driven: ");
  scanf("%f", &miles);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and C++ do not have lazy evaluation. So if you do this:

```
ave_miles = miles / gallons;
scanf("%f", &miles);
scanf("%f", &gallons);
printf("%f\", ave_miles);
```

It won't give you the average of `miles / gallons`.

Instead, the first line will *assign* the division of `miles / gallons` with the value these variables have at that particular moment (that is `0.0 / 0.0`, which will produce a *not a number* or `NaN`).

You want to do this:

```
scanf("%f", &miles);
scanf("%f", &gallons);
ave_miles = miles / gallons;
printf("%f\", ave_miles);
```

Now the division `miles / gallons` will give you the average value of whatever those  variables are holding.

Comment: Thank You, this fixed that problem. So in the case of my accumulators, would I move them as well?

Comment: Yes. You are doing the same thing with them. The program runs sequentially. Every  command like `a=b` will make `a` get the current value of `b`.